# How to compute daily compounded backtest returns closer to real-world results?

Tags: backtesting, strategy, performance, asset-returns

I often run quick tests of trading strategies in my analytics suites by:

1. multiplying a vector of signal (lagged, {-1,0,1}) with a time series
   of daily percentage returns
2. doing a cumulative product of the resulting time series after adding
   1 to each return

This is fairly standard but to be clear:

$$ \text{NAV}_i = \prod_{ j = 1 }^i  (1 + r_j) $$

When I have many assets, I do the first step on each return series, then element-wise sum, and then the second step.

Having run such strategies with real money, I know that the implicit assumption that the portfolio will be rebalanced to constant exposure relative to each day's NAV is unrealistic.

What I would like to know is:

- Does anyone have any other issues with this approach for running backtests? Particularly for multi-underlying strategies?
- To "make" the strategy trade on a monthly basis, would it be sufficient to sum daily returns intra-month (so that there is one summed-up return for each month) and then do the cumulative product in step 2 on the series of these summed returns?

Answer (score 3):

If you do step 1 and step 2 every day, then you indeed assume that you rebalance the strategy *every day*.

If you want to assume differently, for example monthly, you need to first compound the returns for each asset separately during the whole month and then do a weighted sum of the compounded returns using the weights of each asset at the beginning of the period to get the overall period return, without the rebalancing assumption.